# Custom List App available to show user stories and defects for previous sprints

Tags: rally

The custom list app is a nice app, to show a list of items that are currently in Rally.

What I would like to get out of this list as well, is UserStories and Defects from previous Iterations.

A page can be easily setup where you have an iteration filter on top, then a list app underneath. When the page is set to show closed / past iterations it should show the user stories and defects that have been previously assigned to the applied iteration (even if they have another iteration set currently).

Is such an app available? Searching a bit did provide any usefull apps,

Blocking history seems to do a little in that area, but looks only at things that had a blocker flag set:
https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/legacy/BlockingHistoryApp.html

The List from this app on the other hand cannot be modified, therefor I want to combine history with the Custom Grid app as provided by Rally.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What about the Iteration Scope Change app?

Source here:
https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/legacy/IterationScopeChangeApp.html

It's available directly in the app catalog in the product as well.